# Why does the behavior of .trim() and .stroke() modifiers change on a Circle, depending on their order?

Tags: swiftui

I am having trouble understanding why the SwiftUI modifiers `.stroke()` and `.trim()` behave differently on a Circle, depending on which you put first.

In an Xcode playground, this code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Circle()
      .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
  ContentView()
    .padding(10)
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
)
```

results (as expected) in the following image:

[image]

If I only want the outline of the semicircle, I add the `.stroke` modifier:

```swift
Circle()
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
  .stroke() // add this
```

which results in:

[image]

So far, so good. But if I do it backwards, it doesn't work as expected. That is, if I first build the outline of a circle:

```swift
Circle()
  .stroke()
```

[image]

AND THEN I try to obtain the lower half of the outline by doing this:

```swift
Circle()
  .stroke()
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
```

I get an (unexpected) result of:

[image]

Not only that: if I change the `to` argument of `trim` to `0.25`, I get the following:

```swift
Circle()
  .stroke()
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.25)
```

[image]

I know that, in general, the order of SwiftUI modifiers matter, but in this case, I don't understand the results of the code snippets I provided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `stroke` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/stroke(linewidth:)) you are calling has a fairly short implementation. The implementation is essentially this:

```
struct _StrokedShape<S: Shape>: Shape {
    var s: S
    var style: StrokeStyle

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return s
            .path(in: rect)
            .strokedPath(style)
            // strokedPath is defined on Path.
    }
}

extension Shape {
    func stroke(lineWidth: CGFloat = 1) -> some Shape {
        return _StrokedShape(s: self, style: .init(lineWidth: lineWidth))
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that stroking a path always produces a **closed** path.

[The `trim` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/trim(from:to:)#) has a similarly short implementation, which is essentially this:

```
struct _TrimmedShape<S: Shape>: Shape {
    var s: S
    var from: CGFloat
    var to: CGFloat

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return s
            .path(in: rect)
            .trimmedPath(from: from, to: to)
            // trimmedPath is defined on Path.
    }
}

extension Shape {
    func trim(from: CGFloat, to: CGFloat) -> some Shape {
        return _TrimmedShape(s: self, from: from, to: to)
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that trimmed a path usually produces an **open** path.

(I stepped through the implementations of both methods in the debugger to verify that this is how they work.)

Now we understand how SwiftUI implements these modifiers. The other thing to understand is how SwiftUI draws a `Shape`: it calls the `Shape`'s `path(in:)` method, then fills the path with the foreground style (or, on older operating systems, the foreground color). If the path is open, it is automatically closed when filled. The default foreground style is solid black or white (depending on the color scheme).

Armed with this knowledge, we can understand the results you're seeing.

Your first test was this code:

```
    Circle()
      .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
```

which produces this **open** semicircle path:

[image: open semicircle]

which, when filled, is closed to form this **closed** semicircle path:

[image: closed semicircle]

Your second test was this code:

```
Circle()
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
  .stroke() // add this
```

The default stroke `lineWidth` is 1, which makes the resulting path hard to understand, so I'm going to instead use this code:

```
Circle()
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
  .stroke(lineWidth: 5)
```

This strokes the path produced by `trim`—the open semicircle above, producing this **closed** semiannular path:

[image: closed semiannular path]

Filling that closed semiannular path draws a semicircle.

Your third test was this code:

```
Circle()
  .stroke()
```

Again, the default `lineWidth` of 1 would make the result hard to understand, so I'm going to instead use this code:

```
Circle()
  .stroke(lineWidth: 5)
```

This strokes a circle, producing a path containing **two closed circular subpaths**:

[image: two concentric closed circular paths]

It's impossible to tell from the above image, but the subpaths run in opposite directions, so that when filled using [the non-zero winding rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule), it looks like a single circle.

Your fourth test was this code:

```
Circle()
  .stroke()
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
```

Again I'll use a `lineWidth` of 5 instead:

```
Circle()
  .stroke(lineWidth: 5)
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.5)
```

Remember that `stroke` produces a path containing **two** circular subpaths. If these circles had exactly the same radii, then trimming away the latter half of the path would trim away exactly one of those circles. But one of the circles is slightly bigger than the other, and the smaller circle is earlier in the path. So it trims away most, but not all, of the larger circle. It produces a path containing a closed circular subpath, and a tiny open arc subpath:

[image: circular subpath and tiny arc subpath]

which, when filled, closes to a path containing the closed circular subpath and a tiny closed circular segment subpath:

[image: circular subpath and tiny circular segment subpath]

As we make the `lineWidth` smaller, the circles become closer in size. More of the larger circle gets trimmed away, and the remaining arc/segment moves closer to the smaller circle. Here's what happens as we vary the `lineWidth` between 1 and 5:

[image: circular segment shrinking and disappearing into the circle]

At a `lineWidth` of 1, the circular segment is so thin that it doesn't produce a noticeable amount of color when filled, which is why you can't see it at all in your image.

Your fifth and final test was this code:

```
Circle()
  .stroke()
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.25)
```

As usual, I'll use a `lineWidth` of 5 instead:

```
Circle()
  .stroke(lineWidth: 5)
  .trim(from: 0, to: 0.25)
```

which produces this open near-semicircular path:

[image: slightly more than a semicircle]

Since we're trimming away the last 3/4 of the stroked path, we trim away the entire larger circle and almost half of the smaller circle. When filled, it closes to this path:

[image: slightly more than a semicircle, closed]

Your `lineWidth` of 1 makes the circles much closer in size, so you trim away all of the larger circle and almost exactly half of the smaller circle. But if you zoom way in on your image, you'll find that the top edge of the shape is indeed at a slight angle, because it's not a perfect semicircle:

[image: zoomed cropped top edge of fifth image of question]

Comment: Wow, thanks for your patience in figuring out this!