# remove bottom side of border around view

Tags: swiftui

I want to draw a shape where the bottom side of the 'border' is removed, so we can see the background.

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
            .padding(10.0)
            .border(Color.blue, width: 3.0)
            .cornerRadius(4.0)
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm not sure about to achieve this. I've looked at clipStyle and Shapes, but not quite sure what the best approach is.

Comment: See [How To Draw Only Half Stroke To A Shape In Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268965/how-to-draw-only-half-stroke-to-a-shape-in-swift-ui).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI - Add Border to One Edge of an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58632188/swiftui-add-border-to-one-edge-of-an-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to add `overlay` with bottom alignment instead of using `UIBezierPath`. You may want to try this approach:

```swift
Text("Hello World!")
    .padding(10.0)
    .border(Color.blue, width: 3.0)
    .cornerRadius(4.0)
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) { //<- here
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(height: 3) //<- height should be equal to borderWidth above
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a cheesy way of doing it, using `trim(from:to:)`.  If I'm right, the trim guy only runs clockwise, starting at 90 degrees.  So you have to have two rectangles in this case.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World!")
                .padding(10.0)
                .overlay {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0)
                        .trim(from: 0.45, to: 1.0)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3.0)
                    
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4.0)
                        .trim(from: 0.0, to: 0.05)
                        .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 3.0)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result.

[image]